# React native webview keeps cutting off page with web buttons

Tags: react-native, components, android-webview

Is there a way to find the height of the web buttons to add the correct margin at the bottom of the webview?  I keep trying to do some sort of calculation to guess it.

[image]

```
return (
    <>
      <GeneralStatusBarColor
        barStyle={isDarkTheme ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
        backgroundColor={appTheme.detailCard}
      />
      <AppView flex isDarkTheme={isDarkTheme} appColor="detailCard">
        <AppView
          paddingHorizontal={15}
          style={[
            styles.header,
            {
              borderColor: getAppColor(
                isDarkTheme ? 'border' : 'halfWhiteHalfBlack',
                isDarkTheme ? 0.5 : 1,
                isDarkTheme,
              ),
            },
          ]}>
          <AppHeader
            removeHorizontalPadding
            title={title || data?.t || ''}
            onBackPress={onBackPress}
            onHeaderLinksPress={onHeaderLinksPress}
            isDarkTheme={isDarkTheme}
            appTheme={appTheme}
            headerLink={data?.share ? [data?.share] : []}
          />
        </AppView>
        {isPdf && modifiedURL ? (
          <Pdf
            source={source}
            onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages, filePath) => {
              onLoad();
            }}
            trustAllCerts={false}
            onError={error => {
              onLoad();
              console.log(error);
            }}
            onPressLink={uri => {
              console.log(`Link pressed: ${uri}`);
            }}
            style={styles.pdf}
          />
        ) : (
          <WebView
            // onLoadStart={onLoadStart}
            onLoad={onLoad}
            onError={onError}
            onHttpError={onError}
            onMessage={onMessage}
            onFileDownload={onLoad}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            ref={webViewRef}
            mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
            allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
            domStorageEnabled={true}
            onContentProcessDidTerminate={webViewRef.current?.reload}
            onNavigationStateChange={onNavigationStateChange}
            source={{
              uri: modifiedURL,
            }}
            style={{flex: 1, marginBottom: isHtml ? bottom * 2.6 : 20}}
          />
        )}
        {isHtml ? <WebViewButtons webState={webState} isDarkTheme={isDarkTheme} webViewRef={webViewRef} /> : null}
      </AppView>
    </>
```